# In Ubuntu, ensure that the same NIC gets assigned the same interface each time it comes up

Tags: ubuntu, nic, mac-address

I'm running an Ubuntu 9.10 server that has multiple NICs in it. I'd like to make sure that each time the kernel boots up, the NIC with MAC address `01:23:45:67:89:ab` gets assigned to eth0 and the one with MAC address `ba:98:76:54:32:10` gets assigned to eth1.

On Fedora, I was able to do this by specifying the MAC address in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=01:23:45:67:89:ab
# the rest of the configuration goes here
```

(and similarly for ifcfg-eth1).

Is there something equivalent syntax in /etc/network/interfaces for doing this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu uses udev for hardware detection. Everytime a new NIC is found, udev generates a rule for it so it will use the same physical interface eth0, eth1, ...

If you do not change your hardware, you do not have to care about the interface names, they will stay the same. Should you replace a NIC, it will get the next free interface, eg. eth2. To re-assign eth0 to the new NIC you will have to edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and delete the old MAC and change eth2 to eth0.

For more information on udev and networking see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/78017/ubuntu-server-eth0-renamed-to-eth1).

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to look at mapping in /etc/network/interfaces.

> Stanzas beginning with the word "mapping" are used to determine how a logical interface name is chosen for a physical interface that is to be brought up.

There's an example `interfaces` file [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/).  Scroll down and there's:

> mapping eth0 eth1
>       script /path/to/get-mac-address.sh
>       map 11:22:33:44:55:66 lan
>       map AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF internet

Comment: This will work if you use additional "logical" interfaces, but it cannot change the physical interface.

Answer (score -2):

Can I use the mapping option to create multiple logical interfaces for multiple physical interfaces?  Example, I have 2 physical ifaces (eth0, eth1) and I want to add 2 logical interfaces to each of them.  So far I have been unsuccessful in this